# How to spoof the capacity of a USB thumb drive?

Tags: usb, ssd, usb-flash-drive

I would like to load an Xbox One game onto a flash drive (SSD performance is much faster than HDD.)  The game is ~ 6GB, and the flash drive i'd like to utilize is 32GB.  However, Xbox requires that drives capable of loading games meet the following requirements:

USB 3.0 or Greater,
256GB or Larger,
NTFS file format

I want to spoof the size of my 32GB drive so that I can save the game onto the flash drive.

Things I've tried:

Reformat drive via LINUX shell -- only could modify drive free space on exFat.

Any help would be appreciated as I struggle with this tough cookie.

Comment: There is no safe way to do this. The file system is not filled sequentially; there will be attempts to write to blocks outside of your 32GB range. Also, it's likely pointless: most "flash drives" are slower than a HDD. Even some cheaper SSDs have slower sequential access than a HDD.

Comment: Essentially i was reading that the Sata II connection from the HDD was extremely slow, and loading the map from the drive was very slow.  The 150mb/s over USB 3 is quicker.  Mainly i'm unhappy that they have such a large minimum size and was hoping to get around it at a much lower price than a 256GB SSD external drive.

Comment: Unless benchmarked, the vast, vast majority of 32 GB flash drives would struggle to achieve 20 MB/s, let alone 150. You also have to be careful to not mix *drive speeds* and *interface speeds*; SATA 2 is capable of 300 MB/s but most HDDs range 100-200 MB/s sequential and much slower for random access; likewise, USB 3.0 is capable of 640 MB/s but most flash drives are under 20 MB/s sequential. More practically, 'speed' issues for games probably care more about random than sequential speeds, but you'd have to benchmark the drives to compare (many flash drives have *horrendous* random speeds).

Comment: And, of course, that's all ignoring the practical dangers: if you pretend to have more storage than you physically have, at some point it will discard data and that results in corrupted data. Very very bad. You can't assume that you're "only" going to write 8 GB, because the OS will definitely write beyond the 32 GB mark quite quickly even if not all the space below is 'used'. More as you factor in updates, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I'll answer the direct question: there is no way to safely spoof free space and doing so will basically guarantee data corruption. Modern file systems like to write data all over the drive, and will not fill it from start to end.

Now, a more practical solution: consider using what's known as a "SSHD", provides a small SSD cache with HDD backed storage. They can be found at the required capacities for much cheaper than a pure SSD; at the time of writing, they're under 60 USD, e.g. a [500 GB Seagate SSHD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LX4E7FM) or a [1 TB WD SSHD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XV34KVL). They cache the most frequently accessed data on the built-in SSD portion, which should provide most of the speed boost you're looking for.

---

The other issue with using flash drives is they're largely designed for storage at minimal cost. The cheaper ones struggle to reach 20 MB/s (I've seen many under 10 MB/s) *sequential* speeds, far below a HDD's typical 100-200 MB/s. The better ones claim up to 150 MB/s, but even that's only in best-case sequential read - the write speeds tend to hover around 20-30 MB/s (not so relevant to gameplay but it will slow down any updates.

Then there's the random speed. Since they are generally optimised for bulk data transfer, their random access speeds aren't much good. They'll be better than a HDD, to be sure, but still fall far behind a full SSD. Flash drives tend to use cheaper NAND than SSDs, and also have lower-performance controllers, so you cannot assume they will provide SSD-like performance.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it a bit more, you miiiiiiiight get away with marking the majority of the space as bad sectors or otherwise allocating them to a file you never read. But that sounds insanely fragile.